# Paypal - payment without account

Tags: paypal

I need to integrate paypal into online store..

Requirements
 - All credit cards (secure) details should be inputed on PayPal site
 - User do not need paypal account

So there is couple ways of integration

1. Standart IPN - when you redirect
   user to paypal site and he use his
   (or create new) paypal account and
   than redirected back to site
2. PayPal Payments Pro - user input his details including credit card number on my site(and I make payment using API)

But is there a way where I can redirect user to paypal site and he just input a credit card number and redirected back.. So user input just credict card number and that it is - he do not need a paypal account or fill any other fields.. Does it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stanard Paypal does offer you the ability  pay via credit card without a paypal account

https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/general/OptionalAccount-outside

Comment: Found it - there is option in paypal account to enable this

Comment: Haven't found it - there is no option in my paypal account to enable this

Comment: This answer needs to be updated. According to the linked page above (for UK) and [New Website Payments Checkout Makes Shopping Easier - PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside), __"This [optional account] feature is available to Premier and Business account holders only."__ Also note subtle country differences between these two pages regarding Ebay and total payment volumes per month. (cc @AndreyRegentov)

Comment: @mattwilkie as you can see from comment in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475469/paypal-payments-standard-without-creating-paypal-account) question, not all Premier account holders have this ability. And there is no transparent way to know which have and which don't.

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same problem as you, and would like to put my findings on record. With Website Payments Standard, depending on which country your user selects, he/she may or may not need to create a PayPal account. These are the three most typical form submit buttons that he/she may encounter:

Case 1:
**Review and Continue**
No requirement to create an account
Countries: US, Australia, Greece, Hong Kong, India, Taiwan

Case 2:
**Continue**
A so-called *[optional](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=xpt/UserAgreement/ua/PolicyPrivacyWax-outside)* account is created for you, and you will need to register a PayPal account after 10 transactions.

> You will only be able to use PayPal via PayPal Account Optional for up to [10] transactions before we will require you to open a PayPal
>   account with PPEL to enable further use of the PayPal system. At that
>   point you will be required to enter into our standard user agreement
>   to govern the ongoing relationship with PayPal.

Countries: Belgium, Denmark, France, United Kingdom

Case 3:
**Agree and Create Account**
You must create a PayPal account to transact.
Countries: Albania, Algeria, China, Ecuador, Japan, Malaysia, New Zealand, Philippines, Qatar, Russia, Singapore, Vietnam

---

Although most credit card processors require only the card number, card verification code and at most the card expiry date, PayPal requires that address and contact number be provided. I am not sure how PayPal is going to enforce the accuracy of such information without also being a card association. If you get what I mean.