# Hide paypal signup module

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal API for **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** / **DoDirectPayment** and want to hide

> Don't have a PayPal account? Pay with your debit or credit card as a
>   PayPal guest

while buyer redirect to paypal login page to continue checkout
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this post: [Paypal - payment without account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783832/paypal-payment-without-account?rq=1)

> there is option in paypal account to enable this