# Paypal Payments Standard without creating Paypal account

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I want to sell media, and chose PayPal Payments Standard to do it.

According to [official documentation](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons#id089UG0WA0BI) buyer can make a purchase without paypal account. Just enter card number/CVC, name and some other fields and buy.

But when I click on a "Buy now" button created with Paypal button editor - it gives two options: "Pay with my PayPal account" or "Create a PayPal account". There is no option to pay *without* creating a paypal account.

I want not to force buyer to make account and fill a lot of fields. Card number, its expiration date, CVC and maybe first/last name - that's necessary and sufficient. How to make it possible?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to have your customers just pay with credit card without creating account?

Comment: @Ivan Hi. Yes. That's really the matter of country which the account owner belongs to. Country list, as you see from the PP_MTS_Chad's answer, is kind of "paypal's secret" and is not published anywhere. Canada is surely in this list, so the canadian one registered account and there was an option needed.

Answer (score 15):

If your country is a country that supports the feature which allows buyers to pay with a credit card without having a PayPal account, you would just need to enable PayPal account optional in your account.

This can be done by logging into your account and going to your profile.
Once on your profile page, you will need to go to your Website Payment Preferences.
This may be under your selling tools, depending on which type of an account you have.
Once on the Website Payment Preferences page, you will want to set PayPal Account Optional to "ON".  This will then allow your buyers to pay with just a credit card.

Keep in mind that this will only work for supported countries. Additionally, your email address must be confirmed and you **must not** be setting up a subscription, recurring payment or billing agreement.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.paypal.com/worldwide/) the list of countries? My country is in the "Total Payment Solution" section. According to [documentation](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside) I should find "Paypal Account Optional" in `Profile-My selling tools` section since I have Premier account. There is no such option. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the email address for the account that you are trying to set this up on?

Comment: No. StackOverflow doesn't have a private message feature, I don't want to publish email here on public. You see a name on StackOverflow, I have same name specified in paypal profile.

Comment: This is an account, that would not have this feature.

Comment: Could you please explain what's the reason? The [list](https://www.paypal.com/worldwide/) of countries contain country as "Total payment solution", so country is not the reason. The [docs](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside) tells that "Premier" account should have the feature, so the account type is not the reason. Hmm... are there some criterias that PayPal doesn't publish or what?

Comment: This is assuming that the account I looked up was the correct one.  There was only one account, so I assume it was the correct one.  The list that you are referring to, is specifically for what countries can send and receive payments.  This is not a list specifically for what countries have the ability to offer their buyers the option of paying with a credit card only.  There is not a list on the site currently lists these countries.  As to why certain countries do not have this ability, I do not have the specifics on this.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue - I have spent few days integrating PayPal payment for my customers offering them the option to pay also WITHOUT paypal account. Many e.g. elderly customers have no idea how to open PayPal account so I understood, that I can use this feature for my Busineess account. I am from Slovakia/Slovak Republic. Is this also true for Slovakia? Why can I not accept credits cards without opening PayPal account? If this is true, then PayPal is actually misleading millions of people around the world. The list of supported countries should be available. Thanx for explanation.

Comment: It's actually working for me as the client doesn't have to create an account anymore. However, I'm trying to get rid the the adress section. Can this be done?

Answer (score 8):

I spent some time with Paypal customer technical and commercial support:
they say that for security reasons Paypal Standard no longer supports payments without creation of Paypal account.

Currently the only ways to have it is with Paypal Express Checkout and Paypal Pro.

Probably this functionality will be removed also from Paypal Express Checkout

### UPDATE

Working on some other paypal accounts I found out that what was told me is not always true. Sometimes payments without account creation is allowed. It depends on several factors, for example how old the business account is or how many transactions it does. I think in the end is just a matter of trustworthiness of the business account.

Comment: Then why [this page](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/eBayFlowCheckout) is still there?

Comment: This is a really good question. Especially because there are also other pages speaking about that. Paypal in my opinion is not very clear about anything... Fact is that payment without having a paypal account with paypal standard has vanished from all websites where I've used it (several), while is still present on paypal express checkout ones. About the page you linked, I can only say that it appears to be related to some eBay checkout page... maybe the answer lies in this, sorry but I do not really know anything about ebay.

Comment: Security reasons lol. They just wanna add users to boost the stocks.

Comment: In Italy now PP account is required even to pay with PP Express Checkout.

Comment: So in the end, if you want to accept paypal and credit cards, you need a completely different solution for the CC, like another payment gateway or something?

Comment: You can with Paypal, but you have to open a Paypal PRO account https://www.paypal.com/it/webapps/mpp/hosted

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I had the exact same scenario and after days of searching, I finally figured out a workaround to the Guest checkout not appearing for an express checkout.

I basically had to create a PayPal Express Checkout app.

It ended up being much easier than I expected. 
Here are the steps I followed:

1) I logged into my PayPal account and went here to create a paypal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
I saved the sandbox and production Client ID values that were created, I needed them later

2) Then I added the checkout.js script to my checkout page:

PayPal recommends referencing their script and not downloading a local copy to your project.

3) Next, I went here to help create the javascript I would need for my checkout page: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client, 
I used the Client Side REST, and pasted it into my checkout page. I updated the sandbox and production client id values with the client id's I created in step 1 above.

4) I added a hidden variable on the page:  
that I set from the code behind with the grand total including shipping. I know there's other ways to do it, but I'm a creature of habit. :)

5) Then, instead of the hard coded amount in the generated javascript, I grabbed the amount value from the hidden input object: amount: { total: amount.value, currency: 'USD' }

Now, when the customer lands on my checkout page, I display a pretty datagrid/table showing their order details and the total with shipping. When they click the "checkout with paypal" button, paypal performs an express checkout for me with the grand total, and I'm done.