# How to offer Paypal payment option without forcing customers to create a Paypal account?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I want to give customers possibility to pay by credit cards without creating PayPal account. It still super popular in countries like in France, they want to pay by credit card or debit card. It's critical for the business.

From PayPal side it's all done: it's Business account, PayPal integral solution, everything verified, Paypal account optional is checked. The company is based in France and we do checkout in France or in Belgium (these countries accept PayPal account as optional). Business merchant account is verified, card is verified.

But customers on the website are still forced to create a PayPal account on the checkout. I asked PayPal help, they said they checked and it's working on their side (checkout doesn't require to create PayPal account).

On my side, it's different. We have tested on different browsers, different computers, by different people. We are forced to create PayPal account. I dont understand what and where it's wrong and what to do. Anybody had this before?

I'm using Paypal standard option for Woocommerce. Maybe I should switch for Stripe to have this flexibility?

Comment: Hi there. Apologies, I've needed to remove the link to your site - we try to avoid "please check my site" questions here, since links break and change, which will not make for a useful question in the future. If there is anything you can add to your question _in the question itself_ that might shed light on the problem, that would be good.

Comment: Do you need to export any JavaScript buttons/code from your Paypal developer account now you've ticked the "Paypal account optional" widget? I've barely used Paypal, so am grasping at straws.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475469/paypal-payments-standard-without-creating-paypal-account).

Comment: [See this as well](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/paypal-account-optional-not-working-bug) - looks like there is an option in Woocommerce as well. Have you set that up correctly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 2):

It's important to remember that guest checkout is not guaranteed for every transaction under PayPal Standard products. Only low percentage of your customer will be able to enjoy this feature and it also depending a lot on several criteria, such as the location of the seller and the buyer and other points that the system use to identify if the buyer should be able to get the feature. Means our system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons.

Here are a few things to make sure guest checkout is offered as often as possible.

- Verified PayPal account
- Confirmed email address
- Guest Checkout enabled
- add the HTML code `<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing">` (Web Payment Standard Case)

If all of these are met and it's not available then our system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons. This is not a permanent decision and it will be available in the future.

The only way to guarantee the credit card option is to user PayPal Payments Pro Hosted Solution (but this feature depends on country availability). Otherwise they rely on our risk filters to determine eligibility.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/